# Explaining the benefits of using a high-order function in a simple English language

Tags: javascript, binding, functional-programming

Consider this example, i need to know the benefits of using a high-order function as so:

```
function bind(func, object) {
  return function(){
    return func.apply(object, arguments);
  };
}
```

I mean what's the problem with a simple function like so:

```
function bind(func, object) {
  return func.apply(object, arguments);
}
```

Comment: The problem with the second approach is that it doesn't return a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The benefit in your example is that you get [partial application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application):

> Intuitively, partial function application says "if you fix the first arguments of the function, you get a function of the remaining arguments". For example, if function div stands for the division operation `x / y`, then div with the parameter x fixed at 1 (i.e. div 1) is another function: the same as the function `inv` that returns the multiplicative inverse of its argument, defined by `inv(y) = 1 / y`.
>
> The practical motivation for partial application is that very often the functions obtained by supplying some but not all of the arguments to a function are useful; for example, many languages have a function or operator similar to `plus_one`. Partial application makes it easy to define these functions, for example by creating a function that represents the addition operator with 1 bound as its first argument.

In your example, there's three pieces of information:

1. which object
2. which method to call
3. which arguments to supply to that method call

Using your `bind`, you can decide on 1 and 2, while leaving 3 for later.

See [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html) for another example that generalizes partial application beyond just `this`.

Answer (score 2):

This

```
function bind(func, object) {
    return func.apply(object, arguments);
}
```

returns a result of `func` invocation. While `bind` should return a *new* function, which when called will be invoked in proper context (`object`).